# Android Studio: Build folder in app directory erroring out

Tags: java, android, xml, build, android-databinding

I am getting multiple errors in various files in the build folder, which is labeled with "Files under the 'build' folder are generated and should not be edited." I have a hunch that this is happening because I renamed a bunch of class files, methods, and variables to organize the project into an MVVM structure. I am attempting to use data binding if that is relevant.

If these files are automatically generated, why are they causing me errors and not allowing my app to run? and how would I go about fixing this?

I've tried searching google for my issues, editing the affected files in the build folder, looking through build.gradle for any errors (probably missed something), syncing project with gradle.

Comment: Here are some relevant images<https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuv4N.png>
<https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqJMq.png>
<https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGVZo.png>
<https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpYpv.png>
<https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ceyki.png>

Comment: Please post your code snippts, warning, errors in here.

Answer (score 0):

The build folder in Android Studio is a special folder that contains files that are generated automatically when you build your app. These files are essential for your app to run, so you should never edit them manually.

If you're getting errors in the build folder after renaming class files, methods, or variables, it's likely that some of the generated files are out of date. This can happen if you make changes to your code without rebuilding your app. An easy fix for this would be cleaning the project. If you still have the same error, try restarting AS.

Also, make sure you are updating the data binding expressions for the layout files, perhaps you renamed one and forgot to change the data binding.